# C# Can I add Interface methods to a list?

Tags: c#

I just started programming and I dont even know if this is even possible...

I have the following Interface:

```
public interface ISkills
{
    int SelfHeal();
    int AditionDamage();
    int DoubleDamage();
    int DefenseMatrix();
}
```

and the following base class:

```
class NetNavi : ISkills
{
    List<ISkills> skills = new List<ISkills>();
     
    int ISkills.SelfHeal()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    int ISkills.AditionDamage()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    int ISkills.DoubleDamage()
    {
        return 5;
    }

    int ISkills.DefenseMatrix()
    {
        return 5;
    }
     
    
    public void AddSkills(int chosenSkill)
    {
        switch(chosenSkill)
        {
            case 1:
                //add SelfHeal to the list
                break;
            case 2:
                //add AditionDamage to the list
                break;
            case 3:
                //add DoubleDamage to the list
                break;
            case 4:
                //add DefenseMatrix to the list
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In main the user gets asked to choose 2 skills.
How can I add the chosen methods to my list (because the add() doesnt work...) and how can I call the methods in the list then?

Comment: The methods return integers so your skills List has to be of type `List<int>`. Why would you need it to be of type `List<ISkills>`?

Comment: because the methods which i want to add to my list are from the class ISkills

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to achieve. What should your skills list contain?

Comment: You may want to ditch the interface and go with a `List<Func<int>>`. Read up on _delegates_. If you are coming from a Java background, interfaces may seem natural. In C#, delegates make everything simpler

Comment: there is not really a logic... i just want the user to choose 2 skills from 4 and then he should be able to choose one of these 2 in the battle. thats why i want to put them in a list... actually the name of the list should be "selected skills"

Comment: I understand your requirements. But using interfaces this way is not going to help. Even if you find a way to add "interface methods" to a list, then what are you going to do with them? You can just call them and they will return an integer. Then what are you going to do with those integers? How would you know if that integer should be considered Damage or Self-Heal? You should change the way you see the problem. If you explain your requirements more (specially how you are going to use `Skills` list) we will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
class NetNavi : ISkills
    {
        Dictionary<string, Func<int>> skills = new Dictionary<string, Func<int>>();
     
        int SelfHeal()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        int AditionDamage()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        int DoubleDamage()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        int DefenseMatrix()
        {
            return 5;
        }
     
    
            
       

 public void AddSkills(int chosenSkill)
        {
            switch(chosenSkill)
            {
                case 1:
                    Func<int> theFunc = SelfHeal;
                    skills.Add("SelfHeal", theFunc);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Func<int> theFunc = AditionDamage;
                    skills.Add("AditionDamage", theFunc);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Func<int> theFunc = DoubleDamage;
                    skills.Add("DoubleDamage", theFunc);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Func<int> theFunc = DefenseMatrix;
                    skills.Add("DefenseMatrix", theFunc );
                    break;
            }   
        }
}
```

In which by typing `skills["DefenseMatrix"]()` (or instead of `"DefenseMatrix"` any other key `"key"` you defined in `skills.Add("key", theFunc);`) you execute the method.

If there is no matching `"key"` found this will raise an error.

You can check if a key exists by `if (skills.ContainsKey("key"))`

If you actually just wanted to determine which methods the character is allowed to do and which not, you might benefit from looking into `[Flags] enum`'s. It seems `[Flags]` would be a better way.

Comment: As you can see, it is possible. Moreover, it is even possible to create an array of `Func<int>`s and just call `theFuncList[2]()`. But given that you just started programming, I would recommend against such construct. There are usually simpler ways to accomplish whatever you want to do

Comment: @Felix totally agree.

Comment: @SakuraKyoko Nice to hear that! If it answered your problem, consider accepting my answer :)